# Application crash NSRangeException

Tags: ios, html, cordova, ios7, nsrangeexception

We have created a Phonegap application for iOS with Xcode4.5 and integrated Bing map using HTML.
we are using cordova-1.9.0

When we run our application in iOS7 then application crashes with below exception.

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[WebCoreSharedBufferData getBytes:range:]: range {0, 4000} exceeds data length 0'

Application cresh while zoom in - zoom out the map.
map is loaded by using mapdotnet-8.3

Comment: try to check out the range. The error says you are trying to access the range which is beyond the maximum i.e ex: if it is having 0 to 7 characters then you are trying to use the 8 index which is not existing

Comment: You are accessing index outside size. Paste a code so we can help.